# How to Fix play store issue, react native: the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

Already tried

1. adding: android:exported="false" in activity (true,false both tried)
2. ./gradlew clean
3. reinstalled dependencies

Build Gradel:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
    }

AndroidManifest.xml:
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    <service
        android:name="com.hoxfon.react.TwilioVoice.fcm.VoiceFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="ENTER GOOGLE MAP KEY"/>
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
    android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" 
    android:exported="false"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure to add `android:exported="true"`  in src/main/AndroidManifest and false in src/debug/AndroidManifest

also i don't think those lines are needed inside src/main/AndroidManifest

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" 
    android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: I tried with : 
android:exported="true" in src/main/AndroidManifest

Not using any activity in debug manifest file:

Debug Manifest File:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" />
</manifest>

Comment: Same AndroidManifest is working in different project of mine